# Unity C# Add Song on runtime then play that song

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine, runtime

I am trying to allow the user to Import a song using a file browser Add on from the unity store. Currently I am trying to just play the song in the menu, just to see if I have loaded it correctly but it seems I cannot get past this stage. The WWW function makes no sense to me and I will need someone to explain it very simply. In my eyes this should open the file browser, the user then selects that file, then the selected file should be loaded into the audio clip. then the debug play button should play that audio clip, but from pausing the game I can see that the file browser finds the file and has the correct string but the audio is never assigned to the clip correctly. I am using .wav and .ogg files so no problem with formats.

```
public FileBrowser fb = new FileBrowser();
public bool toggleBrowser = true;
public string userAudio;
public AudioSource aSource;
public AudioListener aListener;
public AudioClip aClip;

void Start()
{
    if (aSource == null)
    {
        aSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        aListener = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioListener>();
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    // File browser, cancel returns to menu and select chooses music file to load
    if (fb.draw())
    {
        if (fb.outputFile == null)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("_WaveRider_Menu");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Ouput File = \"" + fb.outputFile.ToString() + "\"");
            // Taking the selected file and assigning it a string
            userAudio = fb.outputFile.ToString();


        }

    }
}

public void playTrack()
{
    //assigns the clip to the audio source and plays it
    aSource.clip = aClip;
    aSource.Play();
}

IEnumerator LoadFilePC(string filePath)
{
    filePath = userAudio;

    print("loading " + filePath);
    //Loading the string file from the File browser
    WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + filePath);

    //create audio clip from the www
    aClip = www.GetAudioClip(false);

    while (!aClip.isReadyToPlay)
    {
        yield return www;
    }           
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that may be causing you some trouble.
I'm not sure how exactly the file browser add-on works, but in the code you posted the PlayTrack() function is never called, and the LoadFilePC coroutine is never started. Even if you're loading the file correctly, it's never being assigned to the AudioSource or playing.

Try adding "playTrack();" at the end of your coroutine, and starting it using the MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine() function after the file is selected.

Comment: Thank you so much! Spot on. Was the Coroutine start that I needed.